# Can we solve a "very" exponential recurrence?

Tags: complexity-theory, recurrence-relation, discrete-mathematics, theory

Can we solve this recurrence relation : $T_n = \exp(T_{n-1})$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

It depends what you mean by "solve". This is tetration, and it has a number of "closed" forms. For example:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}T_0 & = & 1 \\ T_{n+1} & = & 2^{T_n}\end{eqnarray*}$$

If $n \ge 3$, then:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}T_n & = & A(4, n-3) + 3\end{eqnarray*}$$

Where $A()$ is Ackermann's function.

Or using the [Hyperoperation sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}T_n & = & H_4(2,n)\end{eqnarray*}$$

Or in [Knuth's arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}T_n & = & 2 \uparrow \uparrow n\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: In this context does exp(x) mean 2^x, not e^x? I'd assumed the latter (e^x) and was confused by the appearance of 2 in this answer. That said I'm not a computer scientist, I'm so I'm guessing it's a difference in convention specific to the field?

Comment: @bob Tough to say. Unless told otherwise, I tend to assume in contexts like this that "exponential" means "$b^x$ for some $b$".